# Rselenium driver error : driver.version: unknown, SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

It's been a week struggling with this. I've checked every version of chrome, chrome driver, geckodriver, Selenoum.jar, even R. I also replaced a number of rselenium folders in C drive.
Why R cannot sense the Chromedriver and returns SessionNotCreatedException error?
How can I solve this? I'm really desperate cause this is a part of my final assignment for uni,
and I cannot even start it.

- I just want to go with Chrome, not switching to Mozila's Firefox.

OS : Windows 11
R version : 4.1.3
IDE : Rstudio

Chrome : 107.0.5304.107
geckodriver : geckodriver-v0.31.0-win64
chromedrvier : 107.0.5304.62
Selenium : selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1
JAVA : java version "17.0.4.1"

R code ↓

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(RSelenium)

remDr = remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr="localhost",
  port=4445L,
  browserName="chrome")

remDr$open()
```

R error message ↓

```
Selenium message:Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-1', revision: 'd1d3728cae', time: '2019-04-24T16:15:24'
System info: host: 'JIMMMMM', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.x', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.4.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

cmd code ↓

```
C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\r-selenium

C:\r-selenium>java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar -port 4445
15:50:22.250 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 4.0.0-alpha-1, revision: d1d3728cae
15:50:22.384 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4445
15:50:22.816 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
15:50:23.195 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4445
15:50:35.377 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "nativeEvents": true,
  "version": ""
}
15:50:35.387 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
15:50:40.294 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "nativeEvents": true,
  "version": ""
}
15:50:40.297 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

Checked versions of every programm needed.
Checked binman::list_versions("chromedriver") to match the versions of Chrome driver and Chrome.
Reinstalled rsellenium library, Geckodriver, Chromedriver, Selenium.

Comment: I highly recommend Firefox over Chrome when dealing with RSelenium. You kinda bypass a lot of the issues and its dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was all about directories...
I set my working directory as C:\r-selenium, but chromedriver and gecko were C:\r-selenium\chromedriver_win32,
C:\r-selenium\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64 for each.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I've been spending hours trying many of the suggested solutions and this one fixed it.